# Beginner Project, Azure Blog

Tags: c#, azure, blogs

I am wanting to learn about Web Development and Windows azure in particular. I thought creating a blogging application for a personal website would be a nice and simple project to accomplish this.

Does anyone know of  walkthroughs/tutorials that would help lead me down this path, or even better cover this exact topic?

If the reason I am not finding many tutorials on this topic is because of the inability to use Azure in this way, I would love to know of a more appropriate, but still useful, project to do.

Answer (score 2):

Steve Marx's blog is a perfect place to start - if you go back to the start of this - http://blog.smarx.com - then writing a blog is exactly how he started the blog.

Here's some info about his original PDC presentation - http://azurefeeds.com/post/122/Windows_Azure_Blog_Source_Code_from_PDC.aspx - some of the code will be a little out of date now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because most developers advise that "Azure is not for running your blog" due to cost.

Cut your teeth on the training kit: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en

Then head over to Smarx's article for a proof of concept. But if you want a blog ... use Blogger or Wordpress ;)